# Regex for matching a string until the first occurrence of a delimiter

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, regex-greedy

I have a string and I need to match a pattern and discard the rest of the string after the first occurrence of a delimiter after the patter matched

sample string :

> _fw_xx_app_id=xxxxx&adobe_id=59742375247590810332565440942222920249&krux_user=yyyyyyy&User_Agent=zzzzzz&_fw_did_idfa=aaaaaaa&_fw_dpr=2.00&_fw_ae=nonauthenticated&_fwu%3A386123%3Atqxqle5of=1&_fwu%3A386123%3Atshc3wdb8=1

I want to extract only the value that is after key '_fw_ae=' until the first occurrence of &

I tried this

```
regexp_substr(all_request_kv,'_fw_ae=(.+?)&|$',1,1,'e')
```

but this is bringing everything after the _fw_ae= 
like below

> _fw_ae=nonauthenticated&_fwu%3A386123%3Atqxqle5of=1&_fwu%3A386123%3Atshc3wdb8=1
>   where as i only want nonauthenticated in this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a non greedy quantifier, you could use a negated character class `[^&]` matching not an `&` inside a capturing group:

```
_fw_ae=([^&]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oyjH2s/1)

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you! I'm doing it on Snowflake

Comment: You are welcome. I think this is the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#general-usage-notes) which you can use as a reference to check what is supported. I see that it uses POSIX ERE and as far as I know that does not support non greedy quantifiers like `.+?`